# Two parameter search in Excel

Tags: excel, search, vlookup

I have an excel datasheet having data in the following order:

[image: Datasheet]

The first row in the dataset states that an Apple has 3 quality standards (A, B & C) and the price for each particular quality is on that row.

I would like to create a search functionality that allows the user to enter the name of fruit and quality and it would give the respective price.

Can someone help me how to approach this? I don't think a simple `VLOOKUP` would suffice my requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use VLOOKUP, but with MATCH to specify the column index you want to return the value from.

```
 =VLOOKUP(G2,A2:D4,MATCH(G3,A2:D2,0),FALSE)
```

In this case, the lookup value for VLOOKUP is the fruit name, the table range is the table containing the fruit, quality, and price, and the search type is exact.  The third parameter, instead of having a number indicating what column, uses the MATCH formula.  The first parameter is the value to look up (the entered quality), the second parameter is the header row of your table containing the qualities, and the third parameter indicates an exact search.  MATCH will return a number containing the index of the column that matches the entered quality, and that is the column index used by VLOOKUP.

[image: Screenshot of Excel example]